# little endian DataInputStream

Tags: java

Is there any way to force DataInputStream to read little-endian data?? Thx

PS. Doing byte-buffer conversions is not very convinient as I'm dealing with C-type structs that have lots of 32-bit and 16-bit members.

Comment: see http://www.peterfranza.com/2008/09/26/little-endian-input-stream/

Answer (score 29):

Perhaps you can use `ByteBuffer` which allows [`order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order(java.nio.ByteOrder))  After that most of the methods are like `DataInputStream`.

Answer (score 20):

[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) now includes [LittleEndianDataInputStream](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/LittleEndianDataInputStream.html) and [LittleEndianDataOutputStream](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/LittleEndianDataOutputStream.html).

If you aren't already using Guava Peter Lawrey's answer above is probably better.

Comment: This is the best option.