# Endianness on DataInputStream

Tags: java, io, endianness

I have a file format that I want to load that contains raw data for OpenGL objects.

All would be well but that data is encoded little endian.

Is there a java class that does the exact job of DataInputStream but using little endian or do I have to load it byte by byte and perform the conversions myself?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862023/little-endian-datainputstream

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DataInputStream is only big endian.

If you use ByteBuffer you can change the endianness with

```
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```